# Inkscape x64 cannot export pdf with text

Tags: pdf, c#, svg, inkscape

I am using export in 'Inkscape 0.91 x64' and C# to convert an SVG file to PDF. But when I input svg file contain text, out pdf file be blank. I don't know why. Please help me explain and help me fix it.

Many thanks.

Comment: What C# library are you using for conversion? Why don't you export PDF directly from Inkscape? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12652421/605276)

Comment: @Juancho: Thank for answering me. I just use inkscape and C# to convert to PDF file. I try with Inkscape 32bit it works well, but Inkscape 64bit cannot export text.